# Python not releasing memory after deleting loaded pickle variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing an issue which memory not getting released after deleting a variable which assigned to a loaded pickle. for example:

```
with open("/home/public/clusters.pkl", 'rb') as pickle_file:
    pickle_data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
del pickle_data
```

I tried using del, gc.collect, pickle_data = None and addition methods but nothing helped.
the file contains a huge list which after loading it to memory it add ~50GB.
The memory getting released only after the session is done.
I'm using it inside a python web server so I cant restart the web server after each run.

```
proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
collect()

mem0 = proc.memory_info().rss
print(mem0)

with open("/home/public/deep1b/clusters_500k/clusters/clusters.pkl", 'rb') as pickle_file:
    pickle_data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
mem1 = proc.memory_info().rss
print(mem1)

del pickle_data, pickle_file

mem2 = proc.memory_info().rss
print(mem2)

32194560
48298516480
48072097792
```

I also tried using multiprocessing only the thing is that I need to make some copy of this into another object and when I tried to return this other object from the process using a dict it stucked...

Any idea how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dump/load the list items individually, so you don't load all of them into memory at once in the first place?

```
import pickle

# Demo data
data = ['foo', 'bar']

# Store
with open('pickle.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(len(data), f)
    for item in data:
        pickle.dump(item, f)

# Load and process
with open('pickle.dat', 'rb') as f:
    n = pickle.load(f)
    for _ in range(n):
        print(pickle.load(f))
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xCsIwEIb3PMWBQxIQFxcR3BzdHEUkbRMbbHLhGik@fUxahVYwQ5b7vvv/C6/Yot/uAqVkXUCKEGz96DRjKzhqh9CoqFj54AAXbhD5GniliF8Lco5Img02toBBe8Ene5OFwg0Vl6B6MHsG@X2HTxdEl@myVq7ByHFqkMBG7cD6MXVyfr1CjEpOP6FqQPkGAmGt@/5/EVoW8fmYD9DlHWLW4FbiSfm7Fl7OKpD1USwdmdIb)

Comment: Issue is not out of memory. I am able to load all the pickled data.
The issue is that this data getting loaded to memory and not getting released from memory until the session is end.
Im trying to figure how to release this memory after I done with this list.